# Changing Input background colour on invalid

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have this code https://codepen.io/jammydodger29/pen/RwgaVom where the user inputs their details into the fields and depending if its valid or not the background of the input will change. I am currently having a problem with my card field. The alert will trigger if the card isn't valid telling the user that the card details is wrong but it won't change the colour to pink, constantly remaining green (as if its valid). In addition, after clicking ok on the alert, I can still submit the form even if the card field is still incorrect. The code for this is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Technical Challenge</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class = form>
          <form id = "form" form action="mailto:test@test.com" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="name-label" for="name">Name:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                id="name"
                pattern="[A-Za-z!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+"
                title="Please enter a valid name."
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter Your Name"
                required
              />
            
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="email-label" for="email">Email:</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                id="email"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter Your Email"
                required
            />
    
              <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="card-label" for="card">Card:</label>
              <input
                id="cardInput" 
                type="text" 
                size="24" 
                maxlength="20" 
                oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"
                name="cc_number" 
                onblur="
                // save input string and strip out non-numbers
                cc_number_saved = this.value;
                this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
                if(!checkLuhn(this.value)) { 
                alert('Sorry, that is not a valid number - please try again!');
                }"
                " onfocus="
                // restore saved string
                if(this.value != cc_number_saved) this.value = cc_number_saved;
                "
                
                placeholder="Enter a Proxy Credit Card Number."
                required
              />
    
                <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" id="submit" class="submit-button">
                Submit
              </button>
          </form>
         </div> 
      </body>
    </html>
```

```
input:required:valid, input:focus:valid {
  background-color: rgb(137,200,46);
  border: rgb(60,60,59);
}

input:not(:focus):not(:placeholder-shown):invalid {
  background-color: rgb(231,0,100);
  border: rgb(60,60,59);
}
```

```
function checkLuhn(input)
{
  var sum = 0;
  var numdigits = input.length;
  var parity = numdigits % 2;
  for(var i=0; i < numdigits; i++) {
    var digit = parseInt(input.charAt(i))
    if(i % 2 == parity) digit *= 2;
    if(digit > 9) digit -= 9;
    sum += digit;
  }
  return (sum % 10) == 0;
}
```

Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what a valid number input looks like so I will leave checking of that part to you. I extracted your inline js to external js file because such a big amount of inline js hinders readability. Aside from that, you can use `formDOM.checkValidity()` to check if all the fields of a form are valid and
you can also use `field.setCustomValidity()` to set a field to invalid.

```js
function checkLuhn(input)
{
  var sum = 0;
  var numdigits = input.length;
  var parity = numdigits % 2;
  for(var i=0; i < numdigits; i++) {
    var digit = parseInt(input.charAt(i))
    if(i % 2 == parity) digit *= 2;
    if(digit > 9) digit -= 9;
    sum += digit;
  }
  return (sum % 10) == 0;
}
let cc_number_saved = "";
function onBlurEvent(mythis) {
  cc_number_saved = mythis.value;
  mythis.value = mythis.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
  if(!checkLuhn(mythis.value)) { 
    alert('Sorry, that is not a valid number - please try again!');
  }
  mythis.setCustomValidity("Invalid field");
}
function onFocusEvent(mythis) {
  // restore saved string
  // What is this for?
  if(mythis.value != cc_number_saved) mythis.value = cc_number_saved;
}
function onSubmitEvent(mythis) {
  if (!mythis.checkValidity()) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```css
input:required:valid, input:focus:valid {
  background-color: rgb(137,200,46);
  border: rgb(60,60,59);
}

input:not(:focus):not(:placeholder-shown):invalid {
  background-color: rgb(231,0,100);
  border: rgb(60,60,59);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Technical Challenge</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class = form>
          <form id = "form" form action="mailto:test@test.com" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="name-label" for="name">Name:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                id="name"
                pattern="[A-Za-z!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+"
                title="Please enter a valid name."
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter Your Name"
                required
              />
            
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="email-label" for="email">Email:</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                id="email"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter Your Email"
                required
            />
    
              <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="card-label" for="card">Card:</label>
              <input
                id="cardInput" 
                type="text" 
                size="24" 
                maxlength="20" 
                oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"
                name="cc_number" 
                onblur="onBlurEvent(this)"
                onfocus="onFocusEvent(this)"
                placeholder="Enter a Proxy Credit Card Number."
                required
              />
    
                <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button onsubmit"onSubmitEvent(this)" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit-button">
                Submit
              </button>
          </form>
         </div> 
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much! So if 4111-1111-1111-1111 was a valid number where would I go about changing the code to allow this?

Comment: @jammydodger29 That would be a different question since your title is just changing input background. You could ask another question for that since there is a one post, one question policy on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about the one post, one question policy. I will ask the other question now in a separate post. I have also accepted the answer as it does solve the problem of the form submitting if the value is incorrect