# How to get input to accept correct value and change colour?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have this code:

```js
function checkLuhn(input)
{
  var sum = 0;
  var numdigits = input.length;
  var parity = numdigits % 2;
  for(var i=0; i < numdigits; i++) {
    var digit = parseInt(input.charAt(i))
    if(i % 2 == parity) digit *= 2;
    if(digit > 9) digit -= 9;
    sum += digit;
  }
  return (sum % 10) == 0;
}
let cc_number_saved = "";
function onBlurEvent(mythis) {
  cc_number_saved = mythis.value;
  mythis.value = mythis.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
  if(!checkLuhn(mythis.value)) { 
    alert('Sorry, that is not a valid number - please try again!');
  }
  mythis.setCustomValidity("Invalid field");
}
function onFocusEvent(mythis) {
  // restore saved string
  // What is this for?
  if(mythis.value != cc_number_saved) mythis.value = cc_number_saved;
}
function onSubmitEvent(mythis) {
  if (!mythis.checkValidity()) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```css
input:required:valid, input:focus:valid {
  background-color: rgb(137,200,46);
  border: rgb(60,60,59);
}

input:not(:focus):not(:placeholder-shown):invalid {
  background-color: rgb(231,0,100);
  border: rgb(60,60,59);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Technical Challenge</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class = form>
          <form id = "form" form action="mailto:test@test.com" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="name-label" for="name">Name:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                id="name"
                pattern="[A-Za-z!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+"
                title="Please enter a valid name."
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter Your Name"
                required
              />
            
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="email-label" for="email">Email:</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                id="email"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter Your Email"
                required
            />
    
              <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="card-label" for="card">Card:</label>
              <input
                id="cardInput" 
                type="text" 
                size="24" 
                maxlength="20" 
                oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"
                name="cc_number" 
                onblur="onBlurEvent(this)"
                onfocus="onFocusEvent(this)"
                placeholder="Enter a Proxy Credit Card Number."
                required
              />
    
                <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button onsubmit"onSubmitEvent(this)" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit-button">
                Submit
              </button>
          </form>
         </div> 
      </body>
    </html>
```

Currently this code will turn any card input details to red regardless if they are valid (I was previously having problems as detailed here [Changing Input background colour on invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69011840/changing-input-background-colour-on-invalid/69012189?noredirect=1#comment121969534_69012189). However I know that 4111-1111-1111-1111 for example is a valid card number yet the input field will turn red and not allow me to submit the form. My question is how would I go about changing my current code to allow 4111-1111-1111-1111 as well as other valid card numbers to be accepted?

Comment: All your ` class="form-group"` are not closed. And this one is `<div class = form>` instead of `<div class ="form">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you only set `setCustomValidity` if it is really invalid, and if not set it back to blank string

```
function onBlurEvent(mythis) {
  cc_number_saved = mythis.value;
  mythis.value = mythis.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
  if(!checkLuhn(mythis.value)) { 
    alert('Sorry, that is not a valid number - please try again!');
    mythis.setCustomValidity("Invalid field");
    return;// make sure you return here!!
  }
  mythis.setCustomValidity("");
}
```

Working example:

```js
function checkLuhn(input)
{
  var sum = 0;
  var numdigits = input.length;
  var parity = numdigits % 2;
  for(var i=0; i < numdigits; i++) {
    var digit = parseInt(input.charAt(i))
    if(i % 2 == parity) digit *= 2;
    if(digit > 9) digit -= 9;
    sum += digit;
  }
  return (sum % 10) == 0;
}
let cc_number_saved = "";
function onBlurEvent(mythis) {
  cc_number_saved = mythis.value;
  mythis.value = mythis.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
  if(!checkLuhn(mythis.value)) { 
    alert('Sorry, that is not a valid number - please try again!');
    mythis.setCustomValidity("Invalid field");
    return;
  }
  mythis.setCustomValidity("");
}
function onFocusEvent(mythis) {
  // restore saved string
  // What is this for?
  if(mythis.value != cc_number_saved) mythis.value = cc_number_saved;
}
function onSubmitEvent(mythis) {
  if (!mythis.checkValidity()) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```css
input:required:valid, input:focus:valid {
  background-color: rgb(137,200,46);
  border: rgb(60,60,59);
}

input:not(:focus):not(:placeholder-shown):invalid {
  background-color: rgb(231,0,100);
  border: rgb(60,60,59);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Technical Challenge</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class = form>
          <form id = "form" form action="mailto:test@test.com" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="name-label" for="name">Name:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                id="name"
                pattern="[A-Za-z!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+"
                title="Please enter a valid name."
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter Your Name"
                required
              />
            
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="email-label" for="email">Email:</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                id="email"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter Your Email"
                required
            />
    
              <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="card-label" for="card">Card:</label>
              <input
                id="cardInput" 
                type="text" 
                size="24" 
                maxlength="20" 
                oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"
                name="cc_number" 
                onblur="onBlurEvent(this)"
                onfocus="onFocusEvent(this)"
                placeholder="Enter a Proxy Credit Card Number."
                required
              />
    
                <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button onsubmit"onSubmitEvent(this)" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit-button">
                Submit
              </button>
          </form>
         </div> 
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your condition in `checkLuhn` function to make sure that when it is true it shows green, else it is red:

```js
if(checkLuhn(mythis.value)) {
    mythis.setCustomValidity('');
    
  }
  else{
    alert('Sorry, that is not a valid number - please try again!');
    mythis.setCustomValidity("Invalid field");
  }
```

This is what you mostly forgot: `mythis.setCustomValidity('');` to make sure it is valid

### DEMO

```js
function checkLuhn(input)
{
  var sum = 0;
  var numdigits = input.length;
  var parity = numdigits % 2;
  for(var i=0; i < numdigits; i++) {
    var digit = parseInt(input.charAt(i))
    if(i % 2 == parity) digit *= 2;
    if(digit > 9) digit -= 9;
    sum += digit;
  }

  return (sum % 10) == 0;
}
let cc_number_saved = "";

function onBlurEvent(mythis) {
  cc_number_saved = mythis.value;
  mythis.value = mythis.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');

  if(checkLuhn(mythis.value)) {
    mythis.setCustomValidity('');
    
  }
  else{
    alert('Sorry, that is not a valid number - please try again!');
    mythis.setCustomValidity("Invalid field");
  }
  
  
}
function onFocusEvent(mythis) {
  // restore saved string
  // What is this for?
  if(mythis.value != cc_number_saved) mythis.value = cc_number_saved;
}
function onSubmitEvent(mythis) {
  if (!mythis.checkValidity()) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```css
input:required:valid, input:focus:valid {
  background-color: rgb(137,200,46);
  border: rgb(60,60,59);
}

input:not(:focus):not(:placeholder-shown):invalid {
  background-color: rgb(231,0,100);
  border: rgb(60,60,59);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Technical Challenge</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class = form>
          <form id = "form" form action="mailto:test@test.com" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="name-label" for="name">Name:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                id="name"
                pattern="[A-Za-z!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+"
                title="Please enter a valid name."
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter Your Name"
                required
              />
            
            <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="email-label" for="email">Email:</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                id="email"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter Your Email"
                required
            />
    
              <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="card-label" for="card">Card:</label>
              <input
                id="cardInput" 
                type="text" 
                size="24" 
                maxlength="20" 
                oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"
                name="cc_number" 
                onblur="onBlurEvent(this)"
                onfocus="onFocusEvent(this)"
                placeholder="Enter a Proxy Credit Card Number."
                required
              />
    
                <br>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button onsubmit"onSubmitEvent(this)" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit-button">
                Submit
              </button>
          </form>
         </div> 
      </body>
    </html>
```